# Not able to add widget in S3

Tags: android, android-layout

I have made one widget which is open application also to which it is linked. I have tested in many phones, I am able to add on home screen and working fine. But in S3 if i try to add to Home screen it doesn't instead open application.
Not able to figure out what i am missing.